# One HDMI-cable to send video/sound alternately both ways?

Tags: hdmi, tv, htpc

I have a TV and a kind of HTPC*, both with HDMI-out/in. Now I want to connect these so that I can both send the TV-signal to the HTPC HDMI-input and send the HTPC display-signal to the TV HDMI-input. But do I have to use two HDMI-cables for this or can it be done with only one HDMI-cable? I was thinking maybee the HDMI-port for output on the TV and HTPC also supports inputting signals? I so maybee I can both send video/sound both ways with the same cable?

- All-in-one-pc (Acer Aspire 7600U)

The reason I want to do this is to be able to watch a replicated tv signal on the HTPC-screen and also the HTPC-signal on the TV.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this setup? and what HTPC has HDMI input? Usually output ports on things like TV's are so you can pass along the audio to a sound-system separately from the video.

Comment: Ive updated the post body a bit. Its not a ordinary HTPC but a all-in-one-pc used as a HTPC. It has a display with HDMI-input.

Comment: Your TV has an HDMI output? "a replicated tv signal on the HTPC-screen and also the HTPC-Signal on the TV" <-So you want the same thing on both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't so much whether the TV has an HDMI output.

The issue is more about whether your HTPC has an HDMI input... and whether that HDMI input is the SAME as the output.

You state you want to use ONE HDMI cable to do this.  I'm sorry, but you can't.  The reason is that in order to watch TV on your HTPC, you would need a video capture system of some sort.  Even if you had a video card with a video capture system built into it (ATI was making them long before AMD bought them), the capture input would not be the same as the output.  [PCWorld's review](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2016924/acer-aspire-7600u-all-in-one-review-big-screen-little-performance.html) states that the unit has two HDMI inputs, and one HDMI output.  So, no.  You can't do it with one cable.

I don't know the make and model of your TV, so I can't speak as to what outputs it has.  You could, in theory, possibly use two cables though...

Comment: The all-in-one-pc I'm thinking of buying (and using as a sort of HTPC) has HDMI-input and can in fact function as a regular display without even running the PC in it (as I've read). The problem I have now realized is that the TV does not have HDMI-output. On my TV one HDMI-port has ARC which lets the sound go in both directions, but not video. That's too bad...

Comment: If you are thinking of purchasing the Acer Aspire 7600U, as I already said, that AIO has TWO HDMI inputs.  You asked if you could use a single cable and have the signal go in both directions, depending on your need.  The answer to that is no.